# How to avoid empty value when using getValueAt() method?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

When I add values to my `JTable` and perform `save action` the method, it gets performed. The issue is when I enter a single value say `"TEST"` in the `JTable`, `getValueAt(1,0)` returns `empty` . When I enter two values, say the table row count is 2, for `i = 1` ,`getValueAt(1,0)` returns value `"TEST"` and for `i = 2` ,`getValueAt(2,0)` returns value `empty`. I dont know why this is happening.

**Code Snippet:**

```
   private void jbtSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    DefaultTableModel tablemodel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable6.getModel();
    LinkedList<String> paramList = new LinkedList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < tablemodel.getRowCount(); i++) {

        System.out.println("Table row count :" + tablemodel.getRowCount());
        System.out.println("i " + i);
        String rowValue = (String) tablemodel.getValueAt(i, 0);
        paramList.add(rowValue);

        System.out.println("row value :" + rowValue);
        System.out.println(paramList.get(i));

    }
    SamIntegerResult intRes1 = svc.saveTSAServices(token, tsaservice, paramList, idList);

    if (intRes1.isSuccess()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, new JLabel("Saved successfully", JLabel.CENTER), "Save TSA Service", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error saving to database", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

Do you guys have any idea? If so do post.

Comment: Can you share the piece of code where you added the data in JTable

Comment: private void jbtAddrowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        ((DefaultTableModel) jTable6.getModel()).addRow(new Object[]{""});
       }

Comment: I can only see blank string to be added in the data. What is the piece of code where you added values like "TEST" and the other one.

Comment: Hello Aman Chhabra please refer the code snippet ... I added values like "TEST" etc in the jTable and when i save, the method mentioned in the code snippet gets performed

Comment: In the JTable i created, I added three values 1)TSM 2)COB 3)SWIFT.  When i perform save action(code mentioned in the code snippet),third value(SWIFT) is not getting displayed. Below is the Sysouts i have added in the code mentioned in the code snippet: Table row count :3 i=0 row value :TSM | i=1 row value :COB | i =2 row value :"empty". I dont know why i am getting empty value for i=2(third row value) in jTable.

Comment: Hope you understand my issue Aman Chhabra

Comment: I do understand the issue , but the code snippet that you shared jTable6.getModel()).addRow(new Object[]{""}); }  is adding an empty row in table. I am not sure what piece of code you are using to add TSM, COB and SWIFT in JTable

Comment: I have a class called DialogAddTSAServices in that only i have a created a table named jTable6. I have a button "Add Row" when i click that button AddRowActionPerformed gets called ,inside that method, this line is present jTable6.getModel()).addRow(new Object[]{""});

Comment: Anyways you just leave that Aman . Just please refer the code snippet mentioned in the beginning.

Comment: jTable6.getModel()).addRow(new Object[]{""}) this code will just create a new row where i will add value ex: "TEST".  After adding the rows and entering values, i will save the values to the database. This save action is done in the method "jbtSaveActionPerformed" (refer code snippet). I am facing the empty value issue inside this method. Thats why i shared that code in the beginning(code snippet).

Comment: Can you just help me is there any alternate methods for getValueAt(). I searched in net but couldnt find an alternate method. The problem is with getValueAt().

Comment: If you have any doubt regarding the issue ask me Aman

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please try that. It should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try One of these when you enter the last value :

> 1) using  the enter key
>
> 2) tabbing to the next cell
>
> 3) clicking on another cell with the mouse

and then try save.  Hopefully, that will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot aman the issue got resolved when i pressed enter key.

Comment: Great. Nice to know.